# How can we read a varchar column, take the integer part out and add new column incrementing that integer part using script

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to write a SCRIPT for below scenario:

We have a column X with rows value for this column X as X01,X02,X03,X04........

The problem I am stuck with is that I needed to add another row to this table based on the value of the last row that is X04, Well I am able to identify the logic that I need to work which is given below:

1. I need to read value X04
2. Take the integer part 04
3. Increment by 1 => 05
4. Save column value as X05

I am able to pass with the 1st step which is not very hard. The problem that I am facing is the next steps. I have researched and tried quite a lot commands but none worked.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Step 2 and 3: `cast(str as integer) + 1`

Comment: What's the expected result for `X99`?

Comment: What *have* you written so far and why isn't it working?

Comment: @jarlh Expected result for X99 is X100

Comment: @Larnu For step first:  `DECLARE @LastValue varchar(60)
SET @LastValue = (Select Top 1 X from TableName where column like 'somepattern' Order by X desc)` , But from here i am not able to modify the string and make it +1 to the integer part

Print @LastValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below Script

```
CREATE TABLE #table (x varchar(20))

INSERT INTO #table VALUES('X01'),('X02'),('X03'),('X04')

DECLARE @maxno NVARCHAR(20)  
DECLARE @maxstring NVARCHAR(20) 
DECLARE @finalno NVARCHAR(20)  
DECLARE @loopminno INT  =1  -- you can change based on the requirement
DECLARE @loopmaxno INT  =10 -- how many number we want to increment

WHILE @loopminno < @loopmaxno
BEGIN

    select @maxno =  MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(x, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', x), 100) as INT))
        ,  @maxstring = MAX(SUBSTRING(x, 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',x)-1)) 
    from #table 
    where PATINDEX('%[1-9]%',x)>0

    SELECT @finalno = @maxstring + CASE WHEN CAST(@maxno AS INT)<9 THEN '0' ELSE '' END + CAST(@maxno+1 AS VARCHAR(20))

    INSERT INTO #table 
    SELECT @finalno

    SET @loopminno = @loopminno+1
END
```

Comment: A loop is going to be far fr the most performant option here.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be describing:

```
select concat(left(max(x), 1),
              right(concat('00', try_convert(int, right(max(x), 2)) + 1), 2)
from t;
```

This is doing the following:

- Taking the left most character.
- Converting the two right characters to a number and adding one.
- Converting that back to a zero-padded string.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=411fa350412d1bb3eff775edc1c7d64a) is a db<>fiddle.

Now:  That you want to increment a string value seems broken.  You should just use an `identity` column or `sequence` to assign a number.  You can format the value as a string when you query the table -- or use a computed column to store that.

Comment: While it works perfectly with databases with higher compatibility levels but with a database which has a compatibility level of 100, try_convert command is not recognized

Comment: @Bunny . . . Just use `convert()`.  That is an extra check that the values are a number.